# Slide from left View animation

Tags: android, animation, imageview, slide, expand

**Given:**

An `ImageView` and its `Drawable` or `Bitmap`

**Task:**

Need to make an **expanding by sliding from left** effect for an `ImageView`, not exceeding `ImageView` bounds.

I tried to use a translation animation:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:shareInterpolator="false">
    <translate android:fromXDelta="-100%" android:toXDelta="0%"
               android:fromYDelta="0%" android:toYDelta="0%"
               android:duration="3000"/>
</set>
```

but get unnecessary effect like on the image below, when a `Bitmap` is initially drawn on the left side from the ImageView (the animation is about 80% done):

[image]

**So, is it possible to hide `ImageView` content, when it's drawn out of its borders? Or maybe there is another more elegant solution?**

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

What I can understand is that you have that box and you want that loading view to be expanded from left to right. If that is the case then instead of translation animation consider using scale animation.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <scale
        android:duration="3000"
        android:fromXScale="0.0"
        android:fromYScale="1.0"
        android:pivotX="0%"
        android:pivotY="0%"
        android:toXScale="1.0"
        android:toYScale="1.0" />
</set>
```

Comment: Thank you but this is not what I need. There mustn't be any shrinking or stretching for ImageView content. It has to be like "a train going from a tunnel"

Comment: You can play with the Z axis. Keeping stuffs that needs to be visible above the imageView content. Like what I can understand from the above pic, apart from that background everything else can be above the imageView. This way ImageView will slide below the rest of the view. Is this what you want?

Comment: Yes, it is. It can be a possible answer but it might look like "cheap workaround". Thank you for answer. If nothing else works, I will apply this solution.

Answer (score 0):

use imageView.animate().alpha(1).translationX(imageView.getHeight).setDuration(500);